# Calculating difference between a row and its next row (same column) after sorting them based on the same column

Tags: oracle, plsql

How to calculate difference between a row and its next row (same column) after sorting them based on the same column.

Comment: You should include some sample data and what you have tried so far.

Comment: I will keep that in mind, this is my first post here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`select col_name - lead(col_name) over (order by col_name) from table_name`

will do what you need. The result for the largest value in the column should be NULL (since there is no "next row" for that row).

If you also separate by another column, for example by employee_id, you need a partition clause as well, as in

`...over (partition by employee_id order by column_name)...`